# Cherrypy image in HTML

Tags: python-2.7, cherrypy

How do I get an image streamed from `Cherrypy` into an HTML page?

I can get the image on its own, but I'm trying to get it into an HTML outline that I've defined:

```
class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
        plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
        img = StringIO.StringIO()
        plt.savefig(img,format='png')
        imagedata = img.getvalue()
        return """<html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
          <p>Yo!</p>
              <img src=imagedata />
          </body>
        </html>
        """

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

The code above doesn't output anything - not even the `Yo!` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

You have to:

1. Save the figure into a `StringIO` object
2. Get the content of the object with `getvalue()`
3. Encode the content to base64 with `base64.b64encode()`
4. Place that base64 string inside an `img` tag with the correct `data:` arguments, like so:

   ```
   class HelloWorld(object):

       @cherrypy.expose
       def index(self):

           plt.plot([1,2,3,4])

           img = StringIO.StringIO()

           plt.savefig(img,format='png') # step 1.

           imagedata = img.getvalue() # step 2.

           encoded = base64.b64encode(imagedata) # step 3.

           page =  """<html>
             <head></head>
             <body>
                 <img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}" />
             </body>
           </html>
           """
           return page.format(encoded) # step 4.

   cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
   ```